# Telnet Connection Pooling

Tags: python, linux, sockets, telnet

**Background**: I'm currently trying to develop a monitoring system at my job. All the nodes that need to be monitored are accessible via Telnet. Once a Telnet connection has been made, the system needs to execute a couple of commands on the node and process the output.

My problem is that both creating a new connection and running the commands needs time. It takes app. 10s to get a connection up (the TCP connection is established instantly, but some commands need to be run to prepare the connection for use), and an almost equal amount of time to run the command required.

So, I need to come up with a solution that allows me to execute 10-20 of these 10s long commands on the nodes, without collectively taking more than 1min. I was thinking of creating a sort of connection pooler, which I could send the commands to and then it could execute them in parallel, dividing them over available Telnet sessions. I tried to find something similar that I could use (or even just look at to gain some understanding), but I am unable to find anything.

I'm developing on Ubuntu with Python. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit (Update Info)***:
 @Aya @Thomas: A bit more info. I already have a solution in Python that is working, however it is getting difficult to manage the code. Currently I'm using the same approach that you advised, using a per connection Thread. However, the problem is that there is a 10s delay each time a connection is made to a node, and I need to make atleast 10 connections per node per iteration. The time limit for each iteration is 60s, so making a new connection each time is not feasible. It needs to open 10 connections per node at startup and maintain those connections.

What I am looking for is someone who can point out examples of good architecture for something like this?

Comment: If there's only 10-20 nodes you need to check, it's probably not worth adding the additional complexity of connection pooling. You may as well just do them all in parallel with a combination of the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [`telnetlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) modules.

Comment: Do you need to talk to the same node multiple times, and do you have the startup delay each time? If not, I'd go with Aya's proposal to use `threading`, with a job duration of 10 seconds, the overhead won't matter much. Just don't create hundreds of threads when your problem scales up, use a threadpool then.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl The startup delay of 10s is encountered each time a connection is made.

Comment: Also, if I use a ThreadPool, how do I keep the connections persistent? Wouldn't that be more complicated that creating a custom solution based on Threads?

Comment: You can use async sockets, but they are not that easy to maintain, but you can check them out http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html

Comment: Can you somehow collect the commands/queries you want to make and transmit then in a single go?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Like instead of using 10 connections, just use one and batch up the commands? Unfortunately no. Each command takes around 10s and the max. time is limited. That's why it would probably need to be done in parallel over multiple connections.

Comment: Do you telnet into a Unix shell, or into some custom server?  If you're going to a Unix shell you may as well run only one connexion, and start all 10 processes in parallel using a shell command like ``process 1 & process 2 & process 3 & ...``

Comment: @ArminRigo I'm telnetting into a custom server. Thus shell commands are not possible.