# Telnet connection pooling with Netty

Tags: netty, telnet

I have a web-service application which connects to different machines via [telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16383493/262852) to run some telnet commands in each request. Currently in every request it is connecting to a server then executing the telnet commands and after it finishes its job it is cleaning up the resources(closing telnet connection etc) .
Everything is fine up to now.I have a new requirement: instead of creating a new session for each request, an existing connection should be used. If the existing telnet connection is timed-out or closed somehow a brand new session should be created.My client says that this is required since creating new sessions for every request wastes the resources and they have too many clients.Therefore it is allowed only to have one connection for me.

I am using TelnetClient (Apache Commons Net 3.2 API). I googled if i could find "Telnet Connection Pool" or something but i could not find a satisfying answer.

Is there a way to implement "Telnet Connection Pool"?

Comment: I've nvver seen or heard of Telnet connection pooling, and I would be astonished if it made any significant difference. The tasks that you start *with* the Telnet connection surely completely dominate the time used?

Comment: I agree here. It should be possible but still I don't think pooling is much of gain here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.My implementation was maintaining a map which holds an open connection(open forever) per server.I have around 50 serves located different parts of the country. Maintaining a map is always annoying because of synchronization problems.That's why I am looking for such a solution.

Comment: In my opinion, it should never be different from pooling connections for other protocols.  Is it safe to assume that this questions is rather about pooling multiple connections in Netty in general?  If so, it would be nice if you could update the question.